# How can I add dummy bytes to a file?

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-11, metadata, code, binary-files

I am on Windows 11 and I basically care about making the file (a .bin file) seem larger than it is without augmenting the file's function.

I have a 524,288 byte-sized file and I want to make it 4,194,304 bytes by adding dummy bytes to the end of a file.

Please tell me how to do this, I will install a program if needed.

Comment: Exactly that size ?  And the bytes can be any value ?

Comment: Yes, as long as it doesn't change the function or whatever.

Comment: From my answer on the duplicate using `fsutil file seteof filename length` should resize the file using sparce blocks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/sparse-files) essentially the file size is changed but no blocks are actually written to disk. Those blocks will return zeroes for all bytes until they have data actually written to them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use [Neo](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/free-hex-editor-neo/XP9B0HTG55KTCH).  It will allow you to change the file size and do fill operations.  It is free and from Microsoft.

> Free Hex Editor Neo is an extremely fast and flexible binary editor optimized for large files.
>
> A full “basic” editing command set is supported by the editor: you can modify data, insert data, delete data and change file's size. In addition, advanced editing commands, such as Fill and Insert File are provided.
>
> Hex Editor Neo provides the most powerful and flexible solution when it comes to searching and replacing data in files: the Find command is used to search for a pattern and Replace command is used to search for a pattern and then replace it with another pattern. The size of the search and replace pattern may differ and the replace pattern may even be empty.
>
> A number of user interface features, such as toolbars and tool windows are all called to simplify most everyday tasks and make editing faster and simpler.

And I am not associated with Microsoft!

Comment: So how would I add the appropriate amount of null bytes in this program?

Comment: Change the file size and fill.  I havent used this hex editor.  But this one is free. You will need to play with sacrificial files first.  As long as you are appending to the file, it will remain executable.